# qpython not able to download requests module

Tags: qpython

I am using qpython for programming python on android.In my script I am importing requests module and so I have tp install requests module from pip.When I run pip install requests command I get the following error:

```
error build/lib.linux-armv71-2.7/requests/auth.py:operation not permitted qpython
```

I get this error twice while installing requests and so I am not being able to run my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to manually [download requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install), extract and move it to your Lib/site-packages/Requests/ folder, from there python should be able to import from it. I don't see that package available for qpython, it might work out of the box or it might still need to be ported.

After installing qpython on my current device I was able to open the app, go to My QPython ->Scripts and use pip_console.py to try to install it but as you said it fails. I'm going to test later my above recommendation. My install directory is /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ and that is where I'm going to drop the requests library.

Comment: It did. I downloaded [requests-2.3.0.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.3.0.tar.gz#md5=7449ffdc8ec9ac37bbcd286003c80f00) and extracted it with [7Zipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.joa.zipperplus) I did not use the setup.py but instead copied the requests folder over to /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. A simple test with the console to import the library succeeded and I was able to `r = requests.get('http://github.com')` and `r.status_code` to test.

Comment: I tried something similar to download pywebtools, but it has a bunch of dependencies, and I can't work through them all.  Is there any way to run PIP on QPython?

Answer (score 1):

To run pip on qpython just use the steps below:
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'bs4'])

The above is to install bs4 for BeautifulSoup. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The newest version ( 1.3.1 ) from google play has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solution did not work or me...but I did resolve it by downloading the new beta v2.1 from

https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython/releases

Google play did not give me the latest version (I had 1.xx)

I was able to use QPYPY to install requests and it automatically installed the required library urllib3.