# Getting an import error on android while code works on windows (kivy)

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

I'm building an app using kivy/python. I created an apk using buildozer. On windows my code runs perfectly but when I run the apk on my android device it immediately crashes. I ran `adb logcat` to find the error and I think I've found the relevant bit:

```
 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
 I python  :    File "/home/casper/Desktop/MyApp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 17, in <module>
 I python  :    File "/home/casper/Desktop/MyApp/.buildozer/android/app/price.py", line 8, in <module>
 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

This seems weird to me because everything works when I run it on my laptop. Do I need to install `requests` in another directory or something? Thanks!

Comment: You still need to install requests and any other modules you use, does this answer your question? [qpython not able to download requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949261/qpython-not-able-to-download-requests-module)

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the zip request file, but I don't understand fully where I have to extract it.

Comment: You need to find the 'site-packages' folder for whatever python version you are running. It does answer that in the answer I linked...it should look something like this `/sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: Sorry, what I say mee seem a bit stupid but I'm very new to creating apk's. I can't find that folder, I don't know how they are connected but I use kivy and not qpython. Is the folder for kivy different?

Answer (score 0):

yes your code will work perfectly fine while testing on your windows, this is because python has the module 'requests' . But on compiling to apk , you will run into errors because python for android does not have the 'requests' module. .you will need to check alternative libraries that are supported by 'python for android'